# Remove JackRabbit 1.4 node not through API

Tags: java, jackrabbit

Our setup is as follow:
We use JackRabbit 1.4 (I know... It's old..) to store our documents with a database implementations and different machine nodes with indexes that keeps synchronizing.

I need to remove a jackrabbit node with all its childs, but I'm unsure how to do this. I have tried to do so through the JCR-explorer, but every time I delete the node, it keeps coming back. I don't understand JackRabbit that well, but my guess would be that the other indexes keeps it in sync and the node actually gets replaced?

I know I could write a java program implementing the JCR API like the way we currently do in our program. Unfortunately, I would like to avoid this solution because it is a production issue, and it takes our company a very long time before we have a new release on production.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try it with BitKinex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way. So I built a small Java application implementing the JCR API to do it by code.